# _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length

Tags: flutter

My method getting the data from db and displaying on the console. I tried several hints given in the other posts as well with no luck.

```
_getUsers() async {
    print("getting");

    var data = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2/Flutter/getdata.php", body: {
      "date": formattedDate,
    });

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    print(jsonData);
  }
```

However the future builder not able to display:

```
new FutureBuilder(
              future: _getUsers(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: new Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(56.0, 8.0, 56.0, 8.0),

//Here I guarded against the null as well:
                  

child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length == null // showing error here
                              ? 0
                              : snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["branch"]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["count(`branch`)".toString()]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function doesn't return any Future, therefore the `FutureBuilder` is unable to get a `Future` to run on.

```dart
_getUsers() {
    print("getting");

    return http.post("http://10.0.2.2/Flutter/getdata.php", body: {
      "date": formattedDate,
    });
}
```

It needs to return a Future, you shouldn't be using await because the FutureBuilder depends on an actual Future, not data. You obtain the data inside the builder and then decode it.

```dart
new FutureBuilder(
              future: _getUsers(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: new Text('Error ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) { // checking for data
                  return Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 56, vertical: 8),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["branch"]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: new Text(
                                '${snapshot.data[index]["count(`branch`)".toString()]}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 25.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

Answer (score 2):

you should return `jsonData` in `_getUser()`.

```dart
getUsers() async {
    print("getting");

    var data = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2/Flutter/getdata.php", body: {
      "date": formattedDate,
    });

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    return jsonData;
  }
```

, and change this

```dart
itemCount: snapshot.data.length == null // showing error here
                              ? 0
                              : snapshot.data.length,
```

to this

```dart
itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
```

`snapshot.data?` checks whether the `data` is null or not. `??` executes its successor when the predecessor is null.

Comment: Superb..Thanks a lot it solve my day.. been struggling for couple of days..you saved m....

Comment: @raj Great to hear it!

Comment: Thanks a lot @wurikiji , Can you explain why it works in details (with example), It helps. other wise please point me to any articles :)